# Facebook POST user/external_edge error

Tags: facebook, permissions

I recently got Facebook developer alert that the app is receiving large number of API errors from **POST user/external_edge**. I looked into facebook developer documentation and tried googling it but I dint any valuable information.

Did anyone face similar problem ?
What permissions might be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you show the code where the problem happens?

Comment: I am not getting this as a response to facebook graph request and there are no errors being logged on the application server. 
This error was logged at the facebook developer App page in Alert section.

Comment: Did you add some logging to your app to check if the API returns any errors when you for example post a status? If not, I'd recommend adding some logging to see if the API reports any failures and fix them first. If the problem persist, file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs